# Windows application form in VB.NET does not running correctly on Server

Tags: vb.net, winforms, service

I have written a windows form application in VB.NET which sends emails automatically by a queue, when the application first is started on the server its working excellent, but if I disconnect the RDP connection or connect again after that the application seems not running (either in the Task manager) what am I doing wrong? I need the application will always run on the server without any connection who is connected or not and every user could see the task in task manager

Comment: You should create a [windows service application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), *not* a windows form application.

Comment: can I do this with UI? exe file which start the service?

Comment: In short, no. However you could split your application into a service app and a forms app. There's also something called interactive services. Google will provide you with more information.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739961%28v=ws.10%29.aspx